# awk to print out lines for cumulative sum

Tags: awk

I want to print out lines of a file until the cumulative sum of the third field is greater than 0.99, then print out only the first line for which the cumulative sum is greater than or equal to 0.99. However, if field 2 of the first line for which cumulative sum of field 3 is greater than or equal to 0.99 matches field 2 of the next line, then both lines should be printed.

My file looks like:

```
rs76832595 -4.4524 0.501109 
rs74660964 -4.9815 0.49886 
rs12992037 -4.9815 9.8159e-06 
rs934367 -4.3376 3.06953e-06
```

Desired output:

```
rs76832595 -4.4524 0.501109 
rs74660964 -4.9815 0.49886 
rs12992037 -4.9815 9.8159e-06
```

In the above example, the cumulative sum of field 3 exceeds 0.99 at line 2, but I print line 3 as well since field 2 of lines 2 and 3 are equal. If these fields had not been equal, I would print out lines 1 and 2 only.

I have the following command, which works for the cumulative sum, but not for comparing field 2 between adjacent lines:

```
awk '{sum+=$3;print $0;if(sum>=0.99)exit}' file
```

Can someone modify this to incorporate the above requirements?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work according to your specifications:

Given `file` containing

```
rs76832595 -4.4524 0.501109 
rs74660964 -4.9815 0.49886 
rs12992037 -4.9815 9.8159e-06 
rs934367 -4.3376 3.06953e-06
```

The following `awk`-script

```
awk '{sum+=$3; print $0; if(sum >= 0.99 && prev_row == $2)exit;prev_row=$2}' file
```

will produce

```
rs76832595 -4.4524 0.501109
rs74660964 -4.9815 0.49886
rs12992037 -4.9815 9.8159e-06
```

The change in the script consisted of adding a `prev_row=$2` at the end of the statement to keep track of the previous row, and incorporating `prev_row` into the `if`-statement.